# Angular currency input with decimal placeholder

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to do an Angular (v2, but now renamed Angular) component which can simplify the typing of a money amount. To do this, I want to display the ".00" placeholder just after the unit typing. Then, when the user type "." or ",", the placeholder disapear to let him type the decimals.

Like this : 
1- The user type units at first

[image: 1- The user type units at first]

2- The user then type ',' or '.' :

[image: 2- The user then type ',' or '.]

I already added a span to position absolute but it won't follow the typing changes, and making it detect user input and font size to determine it's position is a bit tedious.

Also, I tried with a custom Pipe but the HTML I want to return to format the style as I want is sanitized and displayed as text.

Here is basically what I have done :

```
<span>
        <custom-field-text
            [placeholder]="placeholderValue"
            [pattern]="pattern"
            [value]="value" 
            (change)="onChange($event)">
        </custom-field-text>
        <span [hidden]="!decimalPlaceholder" [ngClass]='setColor()'> {{0 | number:'1.2' | slice:1}} </span>
</span>
```

And in my .ts component definition I have written an onChange method :

```
onChange(value: string): void {

      if(value.indexOf(',') >= 0 || value.indexOf('.') >= 0) {
        this.decimalPlaceholder = true;
        this.placeholderValue = "";
      } else {
        this.decimalPlaceholder = false;
        this.placeholderValue = ".00";
      }
      this.value = value;
  }
```

The placeholder is only shown before input is changed. And if I make a span to position absolute like I did, position will have to be calculated from string size, and font-size and I think its overkilled...

Do you know a trick or something which I can use to achieve this ? thx !

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
 <input type="text" ng-keypress="($event.which >= 48)?changePlaceholder():0" placeholder="{{vm.modelP}}">
```

ANGULAR

```
vm.modelP="" ;         
changePlaceholder(){
    vm.modelP=",00";
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I will post my current code, so you guys will be able to see what I've done. I have already a check, on the method "ngModelChange" which hide or show my custom placeholder. It won't work with the real placeholder as it's only shown if the field is void :(

Answer (score 0):

I somehow managed to make it work, but I still have a problem. I have to make the input text transparent, when it's not a placeholder.

Inside my component, I did :

```
<span>
        <custom-field-text
            class="custom-field-currency-input"
            [placeholder]="'0,00'"
            [pattern]="pattern"
            [value]="value" 
            (change)="onChange($event)">
        </custom-field-text>
        <span class="decimal-placeholder"> 
            <span>{{value}}</span>
            <span [ngClass]='setColor()' *ngIf="placeholderVisibility">{{0 | number:'1.2' | slice:1}}</span>
        </span>
    </span>
```

With this SCSS file :

```
span {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;

        span.decimal-placeholder {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0px;
            top: 40%;
            z-index: 1;

            span {
                display: table-cell;
            }

            span:last-child {
                padding-left: -10px;
                overflow: visible;
            }
        }
    }
```

And this onChange function (placeholderVisibility is to false by default, as the HTML placeholder is active when the field is void):

```
  onChange(value: string): void {

      if(value.indexOf(',') >= 0 || value.indexOf('.') >= 0 || value === "") {
        this.placeholderVisibility = false;
      } else {
        this.placeholderVisibility = true;
      }
      this.placeholderValue = value;
      this.value = value;

  }
```

And I works :) my "virtual input placeholder" is moving at the same time as my typing. There is a slight superposition tho, that's why I want to hide input text.